# Android ListView row color

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I'm trying to change the row color of my listView in customAdapter. There's an array of integer that include 0 and 1, I'm trying to read from the array and change the color of rows like this:

0 = white

1 = yellow

but it shows a yellow color in all rows.
This is my CustomAdapter:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

ArrayList<Integer> test;

Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);


    SqliteHelper checkFav = new SqliteHelper(context);
    checkFav.open();
    test = checkFav.getFavForList();
    checkFav.close();

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pTxt);

        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else


        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

                    int color0 = Color.YELLOW;
        int colorDefault = Color.WHITE;

        switch (test.get(position)){
        case 0:
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorDefault);
            break;
        case 1:
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(color0);
        }       
            holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

And this is my row_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/active_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pTxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast solution (not very nice code, but works):

```
@Override
public int getItem(int position){
  return test.get(position);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  int color0 = ....
  int color1 = ....
  int colorDefault = ...

  switch (test.get(position)) {
     case 0:
             convretview.setBackgroundColor(color0);
             break;
     case 1:
            convretview.setBackgroundColor(color1);
            break;
     default:
           convretview.setBackgroundColor(colorDefault); 
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: It did the job once the list loaded, but when scrolling it down and up the color of rows changes randomly and not in order of the test ArrayList.

Comment: I can not convert from int to RowItem.

Comment: @ Rodion Altshuler thanks a lot for your suggestions get the switch case outside of convertView == null and it did the work.

Answer (score 1):

`getView()` is called for each row in a list so you should not loop over all items in `test` but only handle the one denoted by `position` and you should do that after (not in) the `if (convertView == null)` block.

**Edit**:

`getView()` should do the following things:

- Check if convertView isn't null (if it is, create a new View as you did)
- Check if convertView is of the right type (this only matters if more than one kind of View is used in the list which is not the case here). If the type is wrong, create a new View.

Now we have a valid View for the list row.

- Retrieve the data which affects how to display this row. In your case this would be the result of `test.get(position)`. The `position` is the number of the requested row (starting with 0 at the top of the ListView).
- Adjust the View according to your data (you did this in the for-loop but you should do it only once for the requested entry at `position`).
- Return the View

In more complex situations you may have to do the third step before the second but not here.

Comment: Is it possible to be more specific?appreciate that.

Comment: @Shekarlab I have added more details

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do as you and Rodion Altshuler said below, it load the ListView correctly but when scrolling it up and down, the color of the rows changed randomly not according to the test ArrayList.

Comment: @Shekarlab Rodion's code is incomplete (to show only the relevant parts) so you should show the complete code you use now

Comment: @Shekarlab As before you set the background color only if convertView was initially null but you must set it always.

Comment: @ Michael Butscher as you said put the code outside the convertView == null and it works fine. thanks a lot for your suggestions.